# Read a file in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm quite puzzled with reading files in Node.js.

```
fs.open('./start.html', 'r', function(err, fileToRead){
    if (!err){
        fs.readFile(fileToRead, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(err,data){
            if (!err){
            console.log('received data: ' + data);
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write(data);
            response.end();
            }else{
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }else{
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

File `start.html` is in the same directory with file that tries to open and read it.

However, in the console I get:

> { [Error: ENOENT, open './start.html'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: './start.html' }

Any ideas?

Comment: Chances are the file isn't where you/the code thinks it is.  If the file is in the same directory as the script, try: `path.join(__dirname, 'start.html')`

Comment: Can you console.log("__dirname: " + __dirname); right before you output err?  That will tell what directory is local for your executable at that moment.  There are things you can do to change your location and maybe you are hitting that, maybe the code isn't operating at the __dirname where you think it is.

Comment: The file needs to be in the same directory that you run the node process from.

So if the file is in dir/node/index.html and so is your app.js file but you do:

    node /dir/node/app.js

Then you receive an error. dc5's solution should do the trick.

Comment: use `path.join(__dirname, '/filename.html')` and take reference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56110874/4701635

Comment: This was also helpful for me for NodeJS reading a local file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67579901/470749

Answer (score 317, accepted):

Use `path.join(__dirname, '/start.html')`;

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),    
    filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'start.html');

fs.readFile(filePath, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(err,data){
    if (!err) {
        console.log('received data: ' + data);
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.write(data);
        response.end();
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Thanks to dc5.

Comment: @AramKocharyan Never use *Sync functions in async code. This will lock entire app until the file is read. *Sync functions are designed to be used on app start up, e.g. in modules system.

Comment: Yeah in my case it was a grunt task.

Comment: There is a typo error in your code sample, your `path.join` is useless, use `,` instead of `+`

Comment: this code doesn't seem to be working for me, i still get the same error

Comment: Why it doesn't work using just a plain stringy path, like `../someFolder/myFile.txt`?

Comment: How does this work with `import`?

Answer (score 65):

With Node 0.12, it's possible to do this synchronously now:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

// Buffer mydata
var BUFFER = bufferFile('../public/mydata.png');

function bufferFile(relPath) {
    return fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, relPath)); // zzzz....
}
```

`fs` is the file system.  [readFileSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options) returns a Buffer, or string if you ask.

`fs` correctly assumes relative paths are a security issue.  `path` is a work-around.

To load as a string, specify the encoding:

```js
return fs.readFileSync(path,{ encoding: 'utf8' });
```

Comment: Don't use any `*Sync` methods when programming for the web. These are only appropriate for grunt/gulp tasks, console apps, etc. They pause the entire process while reading. The OP's code references `response` so it's clearly a web app where `readFileSync` is not appropriate.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not there are other use cases (and loading files to a cache at start-up is definitely not one of them), the OP's post is definitely not a case where you want to use `readFileSync`--he's in the middle of processing a web request. This answer was totally inappropriate to the question at hand.

Comment: @SamuelNeff, 7 years later hope you are well.  I disagree with this as premature optimization.  Node is single-threaded event loop, so technically, EVERY function locks the server.  Some functions for longer than others, so you pay your money and take your chances on milliseconds.  It's not anything we need to scold new users about.  It's definitely low-hanging fruit for performance optimization, and a perfectly good pattern for all skill levels.

Comment: "EVERY function locks the server" is only the case for when the function code is running. A synchronous IO call will lock the server for the entire IO call whereas an async IO call will lock only when the function starts and when the IO comes back but not in between (these days with async/await but back then with callbacks). Except in local scripts and maybe at app startup, you never want to do that. This has nothing to do with premature optimization, it's plain and simple wrong. The fact that this answer got 65 upvotes is very disappointing.

Answer (score 42):

1).For ASync :

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile(process.cwd()+"\\text.txt", function(err,data)
            {
                if(err)
                    console.log(err)
                else
                    console.log(data.toString());
            });
```

2).For Sync :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = process.cwd();
var buffer = fs.readFileSync(path + "\\text.txt");
console.log(buffer.toString());
```

Comment: instead of process.cwd() i think you can use __dirname variable

Comment: @IshikawaYoshi `process.cwd()` is the current working directory and `__dirname` is the directory of the current module so they are not the same.

Answer (score 37):

simple synchronous way with node:

```js
let fs = require('fs')

let filename = "your-file.something"

let content = fs.readFileSync(process.cwd() + "/" + filename).toString()

console.log(content)
```

Answer (score 22):

Run this code, it will fetch data from file and display in console

```
function fileread(filename)
{            
   var contents= fs.readFileSync(filename);
   return contents;
}        
var fs =require("fs");  // file system        
var data= fileread("abc.txt");
//module.exports.say =say;
//data.say();
console.log(data.toString());
```

Comment: easy peasy. I needed a straight form.

Comment: why not `var data= fileread("abc.txt");` to `fs.readFileSync(filename);` and delete `fileread()` function :facepalm:

Answer (score 6):

To read the html file from server using `http` module. This is one way to read file from server. If you want to get it on console just remove `http` module declaration.

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile('HTMLPage1.html', function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
      });
      res.write(data);
      res.end();
    } else {
      console.log('error');
    }
  });
});
server.listen(8000, function(req, res) {
  console.log('server listening to localhost 8000');
});
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h1>My Header</h1>
  <p>My paragraph.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The above code is to read the html file on server .you can read the html file on server , by creating server using "http" module. This is the way to response file on server. You can also remove "http" module to get it on console

Comment: Hey there, you might want to include your comment in the answer by clicking the edit button.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know how to read a file, within a directory, and do something with it, here you go. This also shows you how to run a command through the `power shell`. This is in `TypeScript`! I had trouble with this, so I hope this helps someone one day. What this did for me was `webpack` all of my `.ts` files in each of my directories within a certain folder to get ready for deployment. Hope you can put it to use!

```js
import * as fs from 'fs';
let path = require('path');
let pathDir = '/path/to/myFolder';
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

let readInsideSrc = (error: any, files: any, fromPath: any) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error('Could not list the directory.', error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    
    files.forEach((file: any, index: any) => {
        if (file.endsWith('.ts')) {
            //set the path and read the webpack.config.js file as text, replace path
            let config = fs.readFileSync('myFile.js', 'utf8');
            let fileName = file.replace('.ts', '');
            let replacedConfig = config.replace(/__placeholder/g, fileName);

            //write the changes to the file
            fs.writeFileSync('myFile.js', replacedConfig);

            //run the commands wanted
            const output = execSync('npm run scriptName', { encoding: 'utf-8' });
            console.log('OUTPUT:\n', output);

            //rewrite the original file back
            fs.writeFileSync('myFile.js', config);
        }
    });
};

// loop through all files in 'path'
let passToTest = (error: any, files: any) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error('Could not list the directory.', error);
        process.exit(1);
    }

    files.forEach(function (file: any, index: any) {
        let fromPath = path.join(pathDir, file);
        fs.stat(fromPath, function (error2: any, stat: any) {
            if (error2) {
                console.error('Error stating file.', error2);
                return;
            }

            if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                fs.readdir(fromPath, (error3: any, files1: any) => {
                    readInsideSrc(error3, files1, fromPath);
                });
            } else if (stat.isFile()) {
                //do nothing yet
            }

        });
    });
};

//run the bootstrap
fs.readdir(pathDir, passToTest);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

exports.testDir = path.dirname(__filename);
exports.fixturesDir = path.join(exports.testDir, 'fixtures');
exports.libDir = path.join(exports.testDir, '../lib');
exports.tmpDir = path.join(exports.testDir, 'tmp');
exports.PORT = +process.env.NODE_COMMON_PORT || 12346;

// Read File
fs.readFile(exports.tmpDir+'/start.html', 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    got_error = true;
  } else {
    console.log('cat returned some content: ' + content);
    console.log('this shouldn\'t happen as the file doesn\'t exist...');
    //assert.equal(true, false);
  }
});
```

Comment: This answer adds a lot of unnecessary noise. There's a few variables that are not used, meaningless comments, and everything is exported.