# How to call AutoIt functions from a Protractor script?

Tags: javascript, protractor, autoit

I need to call AutoIt functions from a Protractor script (to open Notepad and copy its text, because I am not able to do so using just a Protractor script).

How to call AutoIt functions from a Protractor script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of opening the notepad and copying a text from it (which itself introduces a dependency and make the testing much less reliable), *read the file directly from javascript* (you can do it in, for example, `onPrepare()` function in your protractor config) - `fs` module should help here, see:

- [Read a file in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386361/read-file-in-node-js)