# node.js won't read and display html file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, fs

I'm trying to read and display a basic html file with node.js, but i get no luck, since anything i do it returns the same error.

**Here's the code**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');

var port = 3000;
fs.readFile('./funckcionalnosti.html', function (err, html) {
if (err) {
    throw err;
}
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHeader(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
    response.write(html);
    response.end();
}).listen(3000);
});
```

**The error i get**
[image]

I've read some things about node not dealing with temporary files, or that my file may not be within current script...i already tried moving files, tried _dirname and copying the entire path name, but it still won't work.

Any help please?

Comment: Why are you creating the http server inside the readFile callback??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386361/read-a-file-in-node-js

Comment: @kkaosninja i don't know, but i don't think that's the issue here

Comment: @magreenberg using that code, the problem still wont go away

Comment: That error means a file with that name doesn't exist in the same directory as the script. Did you double check the name and that it's in the same directory?

Comment: yeh. i've managed to solve the problem by first creating new html file again, and then reading it. Dunno how that solved the problem but id did... @mscdex