# How to read one drive file using node,js?

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, passport.js, node-modules, onedrive

I want to read one drive file using Azure OAuth 2.0 in node.js using passport  strategy for Azure Ad 2.0 please help me out with precise solution. I  have tried reading the microsoft blog  "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/drive?view=odsp-graph-online" it didn't help me though any other way to read the file form one drive using node.js will work for me.
Thank you soo much for your generous replies.

Comment: Have you checked this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386361/read-a-file-in-node-js

Comment: yeah the thing is i have to read file from one drive and the link you have shared is reading file locally