# IMG Tag is not displaying given picture in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have user profile component in my reactJS App and I want to display user profile picture on load of component I'm using nodeJS Express as BE and PostgreSQL as DB. Here is what I'm trying to do

```
const [img,setImg] = useState()
let user : any = useSelector((state : any) => state.singleUser)
let {avatar} = user


 useEffect((): void => {
      axios
    .get(`http://localhost:4000/getUser/${match.params.userId}`)
    .then((users) => {
      dispatch(actions.getUser(users.data))
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('--------err', err);
    })
},[])
```

After this i setImg to the img like this :

```
useEffect (() : void => {
setImg(avatar)
console.log('--------img', img);
  })
```

When i `console.log(img)` i get img path like this `uploads/avatar-1594717135245.jpeg.gif`

Here is my img tag : `<img ref={fileRef} src={img} width={'400'} alt={'picture'}/>` it is showing no errors in the console but the problem is it is displaying img for a second and then it dissapears.Any suggestions why and how can i fix it ?

Comment: what is your backend?

Comment: node.js express and database postgreSQL

Comment: check this answer `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386361/read-a-file-in-node-js` and also check how to convert image to base64 string. then return base64 string of image

Answer (score -1):

Try moving the *setImage(users.data.avatar)* directly after the dispatch, you already have the avatar information there. Remove the seconds useEffect, you'll have less moving parts to debug the problem.