# Parse Buffer data to pdf in NextJS 13

Tags: reactjs, pdf, puppeteer, next.js13

I would like to transfer html page layout to PDF with NextJS 13. I created `GET` route handler with `puppeteer`.

```
// app/api/pdf/route.ts 

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'

export async function GET() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  await page.goto('http://localhost:3000')
  await page.emulateMediaType('screen')

  const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4' })

  return NextResponse.json(pdfBuffer)
}
```

After visiting `localhost:3000/api/pdf` I get huge json with type `Buffer` and I'm not able to parse it.

When using NextJS v.12 I was able to have similar handler function which worked as expected.

```
import { NextApiHandler } from "next";
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";

const Handler: NextApiHandler = async (_req, res) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  await page.goto('http://localhost:3000')
  await page.emulateMediaType('screen')

  const buffer = await page.pdf({ format: 'a4' })

  res.end(buffer) // <-- missing in NextJS 13

  await browser.close()
}

export default Handler
```

Difference is I don't have access to `response` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem here is the new Nextjs app router. You still can use pages router (/pages folder) without any problems or differences, but inside app router (app folder) there is new api, for better or not.

No `res.end` now and no `res` parameter at all. Our new `NextResponse` object is somewhat different from old good `Response` one.
Now we have the new syntax: `export async function POST(req, routeParams) {...}`

[This answer shows the new method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76639683/9047572) of returning `Buffer` data.
I'll just copy-paste it:

As per NextJS 13, when using the App Router, you can do in the following way:

```
// before
res.status(200).setHeader('content-type', 'image/png').send(data);

// after
return new Response(data, { headers: { 'content-type': 'image/png' } });
// or
const response = new NextResponse(data)
response.headers.set('content-type', 'image/png');
return response;
```

Note: `data` can be Blob/Stream/Buffer.

For more info, refer to this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/15453#discussioncomment-6226391).

Comment: I hope this comment will help people, as Nextjs docs doesn't seem to give us straight and quick answers.