# How to return image in NextJS as an API route

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13

I am building an API in NextJS 13 that generates a screenshot using puppetter from an URL parameter.

Here's the sample code:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export default async function GET(req, res) {
    const url = req.searchParams.url;

    if (!url) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "URL parameter is required" });
    }

    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: "new"
        });

        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url);

        const screenshot = await page.screenshot({
            encoding: 'base64',
        });

        await browser.close();
        return NextResponse.json(
            { status: 200 },
            { blob: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${screenshot}` },
        );

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return NextResponse.json(
            { error: "Something went wrong" },
            { status: 500 }
        );
    }
}
```

This returns the following error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

When doing a console.log, it is possible to see some data being created but I couldn't figure out how to send a response with a file type.

Any recommendation on how to serve a binary file through this API?

Answer (score 1):

An answer to this question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76639683/6456163), I have modified their suggestion to the code in your specific use case:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export default async function GET(req, res) {
  const url = req.searchParams.url;

  if (!url) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "URL parameter is required" });
  }

  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: "new"
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    const screenshot = await page.screenshot();
    await browser.close();

    const response = new NextResponse(screenshot);
    response.headers.set('content-type', 'image/png');
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: "Something went wrong" },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the error is still appearing. It seems like binary data can't be returned like this in Next13 :(