# How to import a file using ES6 modules, and read its content as a string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

In my standard React app, I need to achieve the following: import a file that sits within my src folder, in order to simply read its content as a string. For example, let's say I have the following code in a file:

```
alert('hey')
```

then in some other file, I would like to do something like this, in pseudo code:

```
import * as string from './someFile.js'

console.log(string)
```

The output of the console.log should be the JS code, as a string:

```
alert('hey')
```

If I could place the file within my public folder, I'd be able to perform an http request and read it as I wish. But the problem is of course, that the file is part of the build process(inside the src folder)

Can this be done?

Comment: Is it specifically javascript file content?

Comment: If this is only part of build you can just use the node fs module...[Read a file in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386361/read-a-file-in-node-js)

Comment: @pilchard Maybe I misspoke. What i mean, is that the file is part of the puzzle that webpack assembles from the files. The fs module isn't available during runtime, and this is when I need to read the file.

Comment: @Gandzal Yes it's js.

Answer (score 1):

i can think about:

1. define constants.js file with following code:

   ```
   export default "alert('vasia')";
   ```
2. import this file from some react file:

   ```
   import vasia from "./constants";

   const App = () => {
     console.log(eval(vasia));
   }
   ```

is that what you r searching for?

But, must warn you: "eval" is evil!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the very same thing but unfortunately found out it is not possible in pure JS as of 2023.

There's a stage 3 TC39 proposal for [Import Assertions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-assertions) which is [available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#browser_compatibility) in [Chromium-based](https://v8.dev/features/import-assertions) browsers but only allows to import JSON files so it certainly would not help in this particular case.

I believe your best bet for now is to use [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to get the content of your file asynchronously.

```js
async function getSampleText() {
    const response = await fetch('someFile.js');
    console.log(
        await response.text()
    );
}
```